# Format a label as ###,###,###.## from a SQL query

Tags: c#-4.0

This is My Code

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn());
sqlConn.Open();

try
{

    string cmdStr = "Select CONVERT (char(12), CONVERT(money,sum(ProductAmt))),CONVERT (char(12), CONVERT(money,sum(ServiceAmt))) from MyTable";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, sqlConn);

    SqlDataReader dR;
    dR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dR.Read())
    {
        label1.Text = (dR[0].ToString()); 
        label1.Text = (dR[1].ToString()); 
    }



}
```

My `Label1` and `label2` output format is `########.##`
I want it to be in `###,###,###.##` format, How can I make it in that kind of Format?

I got error when i try `label1.Text = (dR[0].ToString("N2"))`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of error arises? please edit

Comment: Also please try to use Console.out.WriteLine to "echo" the content of variables before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that will work:

```
public static string GetCurrencyString(string currString)
{
    decimal moneyvalue;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(currString, out moneyvalue))
    {
        return String.Format("{0:C}", moneyvalue);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
label1.Text = GetCurrencyString(dR[0].ToString())
```